# Help with concept question - Production Org versus Production Environment

Tags: deployment

I am working through Focus on Force questions while preparing for Advanced Admin exam.  Can someone explain why the first answer is correct and the 2nd is not.

1. Apex tests are only required to run when deploying Apex components to a Production org.
2. Apex tests are always run when deploying Apex components to a Production environment.

Perhaps they are saying they aren't always run when deploying because a validation may have been done before deploying.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest here that a production environment is any org that you login to using login.salesforce.com rather than test,salesforce.com, and that includes developer orgs as well as production orgs. Tests do not have to be executed when deploying to a dev org.

NB: personally I believe this is a rather ridiculous question to be set since most people use the two terms interchangeably to mean the same thing.